# when click on men category then show breadcrumb is like Home > Clothing > Men's Clothing

Tags: magento, categories

When click on "men" category, in Magento, how do I show breadcrumb like:

```
Home  >  Clothing  >  Men's Clothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, Men should be a subcategory of Clothing.

Second, you would have to edit the breadcrumbs so on your spefic category level it shows the name of it's parent category (clothing in this case)

Comment: i need to clothing category is only one and two diffrent category like men and women ,to click on men, men clothing category is show.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about your category structure?

Comment: categorization is like " http://www.flipkart.com/lifestyle/bags-wallets-belts  " clothingin three store ->(i) men (ii)women (iii)kids